# sorting of array using javascript consists of alphabets and numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/seatlt',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: data,
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(res) {
        $.each(res, function(i, v) {
            $.each(v, function(j, w) {
                var ggg = w.name;                                    
                vvv.push(ggg);
            })
        })
    }
})
```

In console.log(vvv) I got the output as:

["22", "A", "23", "B", "24", "C", "25", "D", "26", "E", "27", "F", "28", "29", "30", "31", "10", "32", "11", "33", "12", "34", "13", "35", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "20", "21"].

But I want the output as:

["A", "B","C","D","E", "F","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",  "21",     "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"].

Comment: Sort the array maybe???

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing blind, but this should do the trick.

```
res.sort(function(a, b) {
  var AisNumber = a % 1 === 0;
  var BisNumber = b % 1 === 0;
  if (AisNumber && BisNumber) { 
    return Number(a) - Number(b);
  } else if (AisNumber && !BisNumber) {
    return 1;
  } else if (!AisNumber && BisNumber) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: by using your suggestion iam getting the output as

["A", "C", "D", "E", "B", "F", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"]

Comment: @venkatesh Isn't that the output you wanted?

Comment: yes but iwant in order as 

["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"]

Answer (score 0):

sort the array?

```
vvv.sort();
```

That works for me. But and you can sort the numbers as well, e.g:

```
var arr = ["A", "9", "B", "1", "8", "9", "C", "10", "11", "17", "20", "21", "30", "31", "35"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    try{
        arr[i] = eval(arr[i]);
    }
    catch (err) {
        //ignore
    }
}
arr.sort();
alert(arr);
```

Comment: i have used the vvv.sort but the alphabets are coming in the middle of numbers

Comment: That's odd... for me it works as expected: var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"];
   arr.sort();
   alert(arr);

Answer (score 0):

You could check for number and sort this values at the bottom and the rest to top.

```
return isNumber(a) - isNumber(b) || a - b || a > b || -(a < b);
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                check group
//                                  ^^^^^                       order numbers
//                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  order strings
```

```js
var array = ["22", "A", "23", "B", "24", "C", "25", "D", "26", "E", "27", "F", "28", "29", "30", "31", "10", "32", "11", "33", "12", "34", "13", "35", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "20", "21"];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function isNumber(v) { return (+v).toString() === v; }
    return isNumber(a) - isNumber(b) || a - b || a > b || -(a < b);
});

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```